# How to hide/disable VSCode LiveShare "Start Discussion"

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-liveshare

I mean this gray line after the line numbers:

[image]

Its from the LiveShare extension.

I would like to hide or disable it, I could not find anything about in the extension settings.

I wonder if someone knows how?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to solution to the other answer, is to search for and choose this command in the command palette (CTRL+P by default):

```
>Live Share: Stop Collaboration Session
```

Answer (score 2):

Click your name in the bottom bar:

[image]

Then click "End collaboration" in the popup menu

Answer (score 2):

From the command palette, click "Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)" and add this line within the curly braces:

```json
"comments.visible": false,
```