# How can I hide "start discussion" line in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to hide the vertical line as shown in [How to hide/disable VSCode LiveShare "Start Discussion"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674241/how-to-hide-disable-vscode-liveshare-start-discussion).

However, since I have not started a Live Share session, I do not know how to do this.

I would appreciate it if anyone here could help us solve this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a new user here and it doesn't appear I can comment yet, so I am posting this as an answer instead, apologies if it is not applicable or for any confusion: More information on what extensions you're using would be helpful. Do you use the GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension? I recently had the same issue you describe (and had not started LiveShare) and after examination I concluded the vertical line related to the GitHub Pull Requests and Issues extension (which I was not using in practice anyway) and so I uninstalled the aforementioned GitHub extension and that eliminated the unwanted discussion vertical lines. So, if you've been using aforementioned GitHub extension, perhaps the solution relates to that.

Comment: Thanks! I believe you are right, I uninstalled my Github Pull Requests and Issue extension, and the vertical line disappeared. I will start an issue at the extension GitHub repo to find out how to hide this vertical line.

Answer (score 1):

This seems something built into VSCode and used by several extensions (as opposed to something that an extension contributes).

There doesn't seem to be a setting that affects it, but there's a command that toggles it: in the palette it's available as "Comments: Toggle Editor Commenting" (and its corresponding action is `workbench.action.toggleCommenting`).

Reference: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/3645#issuecomment-1165489590